# Getting featured image of particular size.

Tags: post-thumbnails

For [my site](http://320press.com/wpbs/) I use WordPress 3.6, and a wp-bootstrap theme that is built on bones framework.

When I set a featured image for a particular post, I see that the image is automatically saved at 6 different sizes:

<sup>Dashrath-Manjhi.jpg (Original Image)

Dashrath-Manjhi-620x400.jpg

Dashrath-Manjhi-300x197.jpg

Dashrath-Manjhi-250x300.jpg

Dashrath-Manjhi-150x150.jpg

Dashrath-Manjhi-125x125.jpg</sup>

**Q#1:** How to call a particular image using `the_post_thumbnail()`?

`the_post_thumbnail('small')`, `the_post_thumbnail('medium')`, `the_post_thumbnail('large')` always displaying the full size image.

I also gone through the theme documentation, I can't find how can I call.

**Q#2:** I would like to know whether this is WordPress based, or theme based?

Any ideas on how can I get the image of particular size using `the_post_thumbnail()` function would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the WP-Admin » Settings » Media. There you will find all the image sizes a theme creates. Basically the WordPress by default creates three sizes unless the Original:

- **Large** size (Default: 1024 x 1024)
- **Medium** size (Default: 300 x 300)
- **Thumbnail** size (Default: 150 x 150)

From the admin panel you can change their value too.

> **NOTE:** Changing image dimensions can only work on new uploads after a successful save of the settings. Otherwise after a settings save you have to resize your images with a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails%E2%80%8E) by Viper007Bond.

**A#2:** Yes, the feature, unless the default three is basically Theme based.
**A#1:** You can call particular image sizes with `<?php the_post_thumbnail('image-slug') ?>`. And most the cases the `image-slug`, as I mentioned it, is the left-hand name of the size in the Media settings page.

> **NOTE:** In general, code related to new image sizes are mentioned in the Theme's `functions.php` with a function named [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).
>   <sub>**Syntax:** `<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>`</sub>

Inspect and find accordingly if you fail with the Media settings' image size names. Good luck!

Comment: I see only three sizes in WP-Admin -> Settings -> Media. Thumbnail 150*150, Medium Size 300*300, Large Size 1024*1024, But i am sure there are 5 different variants of uploaded image, The sizes are also not consistent (I guess it depends on the width of uploaded image). You can download wp-bootstrap theme here http://320press.com/wpbs/ & test it for your self. Also I see 3 add_image_size on theme functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Your theme may have added support for additional images. In the functions.php file look for `add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );`.

You can add your own as well. Take a look at the [codex for this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).